# TYPO3 & real url: typolink adds url part from subdirectory which should be skipped

Tags: php, url, typo3, realurl

I have a sub directory in which typo3 resides. It is called "website". The DNS is pointing in this subdirectory. Now I generate the URL of the current site:

```
$typolink_conf = array(
            "title" => $this->site['page_title'],
            "ATagParams" =>'',
            "no_cache" => 0,
            "parameter" => $this->site['id'],
            "useCacheHash" => 1
        );

$this->site['url'] = $this->cObj->typolink($this->site['page_title'], $typolink_conf);
```

On the start page I get `www.domain.com/website` from this typolink. I cleared the caches (Typo3, Real Url) but the part "website" is always generated. I also set the base URL

```
config {
        baseURL = http://www.domain.com/
        simulateStaticDocuments = 0
        tx_realurl_enable = 1
}
```

Can somenone give me a hint where does this URL part is coming from? I'm using Typo3 4.6.3 and RealURL 1.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical solution is placing each TYPO3 project in subdomain, as they are available at almost all Hosting Providers for free without limits. I would recommend that as this is definitely fastest way and you do not need to remember that issue each time when creating new TYPO3 instance.

If you can't use the subdomain, edit your `.htaccess`, there is a line which you should change:

```
# Change this path, if your TYPO3 installation is located in a subdirectory of the website root.
#RewriteBase /
```

Comment: It is only one TYPO3 project. `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` should point in this directory. I had commented out the `RewriteBase`. Now I switched to `RewriteBase /website`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Hmmm, so it looks like wrong Vhost config as your domain doesn't point the `/var/www/website` but `/var/www`. Create file `/var/www/website/test.php` (of course in correct path) put there anything (some echo) and check if it's available at  `http://www.domain.com/website/test.php` or at `http://www.domain.com/test.php` also rename the `.htaccess` file to something else, to check if this doesn't cause some redirections.

Comment: `/www/home/website/` is my correct path. Now with activated `.htaccess` and `#RewriteBase /`: If I call `http://www.domain.com/website/test.php` I get a TYPO3 error: `Page Not Found - Reason: File "test.php" was not found (2)!`. If I call `http://www.domain.com/test.php` everything works fine. Now without `.htaccess`: If I call `http://www.domain.com/website/test.php` I get 404 page not found. If I call `http://www.domain.com/test.php` everything works.

Comment: Hmmmm, have no more ideas, last suggestion : check the `Domain record` at the main page (Beckand, Mod > List, Domain) if it exists, if it's correct and doesn't contain redirection to that terrible folder :/

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I look with List on the records with id=0 and id=1 I can't find a `Domain record` ...

Comment: Create one then (at page right after uid=0) not quite sure if it will help you, as I can't imagine what your problem is about, but there should be such.

Comment: use `absRefPrefix` instead of `baseURL`